# bootstrap 3 increase text background color size and toggle on each tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first work with css and Bootstrap. As shown in attached image, I want the green color of text TEST to be green to be applied to that all yellow highlighted rectangle. how can I do that? Also, I want to toggle the active color whenever I click on test1 and test2.

My code is as below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <nav class="col-md-11">
                <span class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/test/" class="navbar-item">
                        <img class="some-class"
                             src="<myUrl>">
                    </a>
                <a tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="${some-text}" class="navbar-brand-test" href="<myUrl>">TEST</a>
                </span>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="test1"><a href="<myUrl>" >Test1</a></li>
                    <li class="test1"><a href='<myUrl>' >Test2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

css for navbar-brand-test, I just updated the existing code:

```
.navbar-brand-test,
.navbar-brand-test:hover,
.navbar-brand-test:focus {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5fc17c;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

When I did as suggested by TKD21 in the answer below, It worked but as you see in second image, the BG collor filled the logo (yellow part in second image) as well. I want the logo to be separate than that BG color

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the green background of the text "TEST" to be applied to ALL of the yellow triangle,yes?

If that is indeed the case, consider doing the following:

- Change your `<span class='navbar-header'>` to `<span class='col-md-1 navbar-header'>` and add a color class or style rule of your choosing
- Change your `<span class='navbar-header'></span>` to `<div class='col-md-1 navbar-header'></div>` and add a color class or style rule of your choosing

Though the two solutions seem identical, **the second is less prone to breaking on window resize**.

If you need a bigger green background size, just play around with the `col-md-<number>` Bootstrap classes.

The results from my testing can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUZH4.jpg)

Comment: your second idea got very close to my requirement but not exactly as the BG color came on the background of Logo Image as well as you can see in second image above

Comment: About your issue in your follow-up comment --> Use pure JavaScript or jQuery to dynamically add and remove your color class. This can be done by setting **event listeners** to the links in the `<nav>` tag, which add and remove your color class, depending on which link was clicked last. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). and                          
 [this] (https://api.jquery.com/click/). can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, below code did a trick. Slightly modified version of the answer by TKD21. Moved logo url below col-md-11 and added div instead of span

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <nav class="col-md-11">
              <a href="/test/" class="navbar-item"><img class="some-class"src="<myUrl>">
              </a>
                <div class="col-md-1 navbar-header" style="background-color: #5fc17c;">
                <a tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="${some-text}" class="navbar-brand-test" href="<myUrl>">TEST</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="test1"><a href="<myUrl>" >Test1</a></li>
                    <li class="test1"><a href='<myUrl>' >Test2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Now only issue I have is each tab should be active with green color when I click on Test1 or Test2. Will update here when I resolve it

[image]